# How can i increase the gap between the <i> tags and add vertical lines between them

Tags: html, css

I need to create the spacing between the two `<i>` tags, and make a vertical line in between them.

Here is my code:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#left_col {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
#right_col {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left_col">
    <p>Are you a Developer?</p>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 20px;">  
            Register Your Project Online</i> 
    <br><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            Wait for Project Approval </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            Raise funding in 90 days </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            Provide Regular construction updates </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            Complete and Sell Project </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            Destribute funds to Investor </i> 
  </div>
```

How can I increase the gaping between the `<i>` tag and add a vertical line at the end of every line?

Comment: wrap the i tags in a p tag and assing a margin to the p tags

Answer (score 1):

Like this is one way. I think you want a **vertical** line like this :

```css
#wrap {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#left_col {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
#right_col {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.cont i {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding:5px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.divider {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  border-right:solid;
  border-left-color: black;
}

.divider2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-left:solid;
  border-left-color: black;
}
```

```html
   <div id="wrap">
      <div id="left_col" class="cont">
        <p>Are you a Developer?</p>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 20px;">  
                Register Your Project Online</i> 
         <div class="divider"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
                Wait for Project Approval </i>
<div class="divider"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
                Raise funding in 90 days </i>
<div class="divider"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
                Provide Regular construction updates </i>
<div class="divider"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
                Complete and Sell Project </i>
<div class="divider"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
                Destribute funds to Investor </i> 
      </div>
</div>
```

I have put two classes `divider` , `divider2`, change and play with width and height and `border-left` and `border-right` to get your desire line.

BTW, You may also want to check [bootstrap timeline](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive)

Comment: @Faraz i need the vertical line like this, thanks but i need the line under the <i> tag.

Comment: See this @Farzad https://i.gyazo.com/5ec7ba0ed5621b8b809fcb185cf383b7.png  ~Just like this,

Comment: I have put two class divider , divider2, change and play with , width and height to get your desire line. @J.DOe

Comment: @J.DOe, You may want to check the link above if you need something like timeline

Comment: perfect,this timeline i am looking for, but can i place it in two columns?

Comment: if you see the image, can i place timeline into two columns just llike in the picture i had shown on the above comment.

Comment: You can use two separate timeline in two col-lg-6 in a row  or act like http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/XMxgK and use both left and right in one block. However, you need to handle the phone view (responsiveness), cause maybe it is so small to use two timeline in a row .

Comment: Thanks man,but i can't move the <divider> in center, padding-left,seems not to be working

Comment: @J.DOe , you mean like above, I made it center

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line-height to the i and then to get the line under you add a

```
hr
```

tag.

```css
i, cite, em, var, address, dfn {
    line-height: 30px;
}
#wrap {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#left_col {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
#right_col {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left_col">
    <p>Are you a Developer?</p>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 20px;">  
          Register Your Project Online</i> 
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
          <hr>
            Wait for Project Approval </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            <hr>
            Raise funding in 90 days </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            <hr>
            Provide Regular construction updates </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            <hr>
            Complete and Sell Project </i>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-left: 10px;"> 
            <hr>
            Destribute funds to Investor </i> 
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks, but it is a horizontal line, i need a vertical line

Comment: check mine @J.DOe, is it what you are looking for as vertical?

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi check out my latest comment.